# Disable caching of routes in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a Router with some Async Routes. It works pretty well so far, but one issue I have is that it doesn't reload the javascript files.

Currently I'm using the loader like this (using $script.js to get and execure the JS file):

```
new ng.router.AsyncRoute({
    path: '/' + pName + '/' + entryName,
    loader: () => {
        let q = new Promise(function(resolve) {
            console.log("Loading...");
            $script(['js/' + pName + '/' + entryName + '-c.js'], function() {
                resolve();
            });
        });
        return q.then(() => app[pascalCase(fullName) + "Cmp"]);
    },
    name: pascalCase(fullName),
    useAsDefault: false,
})
```

However, the `console.log("Loading...")` only gets executed the first time when I'm navigating that route, but not any subsequent times.

The reason why this is a problem is because A: I want the pages to be completely reset to the start (I don't just have Angular Components there, but also custom Javascript) and B: I would like to get rid of all the components and other objects in the memory because I don't want the users browser to get filled with more and more memory the longer he uses my site (as it is fairly big).

iirc on the Angular UI Router for Angular 1 I could just disable caching to force the reload, but how can I achieve this on Angular 2?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to tell it not to cache your page, by sending the appropriate headers or using these meta tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

and this might help too for doing a hard reload

```
location.reload(true);
```

Comment: I do want the javascript-files to be cached by the browser though. I just want the Javascript to be executed again. Currently the NG2 Router is not actually attempting to read the JS-File another time out of the browser cache and execute it again. I want the router to reexecute my loader.